# Rails associations and Thinking Sphinx Indexing to refactor search method in controller

Tags: associations, ruby-on-rails-3.2, thinking-sphinx, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm working with a old database and drawing blank on how to set up the association and index it with Thinking Sphinx. I want to index the People and Group's skill.

I have Users. Users can create People and Groups. People and Groups have a single skill through Sharing_Skill.

people and groups tables: ID field, Name field

sharings_skills table: ID field, Skill_ID field, Marker_ID(which is the person/group_id), Marker_Type ("Group" or "Person")

skills table: ID field, Name field

How do I setup the rails association and index the skills of the person or group in the Person model or Group model.

my main goal is to refactor my search by indexing the person skills in the person model and searching the name, tags and skills together, instead of searching skills, sharing_skills and people separate like this:

This is in my Person model.

```rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags

  attr_accessible :name, :tag_list

  validates_presence_of :name

  belongs_to :marker_image, :class_name => "Photo", :foreign_key => "marker_image_id"
  belongs_to :user

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: [:slugged, :history]

  define_index do
    indexes name
    indexes tag_taggings.tag(:name), :as => :tags
    has :id
    has created_at
  end
```

This is in my Search Controller

```rb
#PERSON SEARCH
if params[:marker_type].nil? or params[:marker_type].empty? or params[:marker_type] == "Person"
  #SEARCH NAME, TAGS, (Need to fix skills)
  conditions = {}
  %w(name tags).each do |i|
    i = i.to_sym
    next unless params[i]
    conditions[i] = params[i]
  end

  person = Person.search_for_ids(params[:search], :conditions => conditions, :per_page => 999999)
  if !person.empty?
    person_ids << person
  end

  #SEARCH SKILLS IN PERSON MODEL
  skills = Skill.search_for_ids(params[:search], :per_page => 99999)
  check_skills_available_persons = SharingsSkill.search(:conditions => {:marker_type => 'Person'}, :with => {:skill_id => skills}, :per_page => 99999)
  if !check_skills_available_persons.empty?
    check_people_by_skills = Person.search(:with => {:id => check_skills_available_persons.collect{|x|x.marker_id}})
    if !check_people_by_skills.empty?
      check_people_by_skills.each do |p_skill|
        person_ids << p_skill.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Only need help setting this up for person, group is the same can copy it over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watched through "Rails 3 Essential Training" chapter on associations and read through Rails guides write up on Active Record associations. Before I was searching the name, the tags, the skill individually and collecting the ID's in succession. With the proper polymorphic association you can search all the parameters in a single search method.

Person Model.

```
has_one :sharing_skill, :as => :marker, :conditions => ['marker_type = ?', 'Person']
has_one :skill, :through => :sharing_skill

define_index do
  indexes name
  indexes tag_taggings.tag(:name), :as => :tags
  indexes skill(:name), :as => :skill
  has :id
  has created_at
end
```

Group Model.

```
has_one :sharing_skill, :as => :marker, :conditions => ['marker_type = ?', 'Group']
has_one :skill, :through => :sharing_skill

define_index do
  indexes name
  indexes tag_taggings.tag(:name), :as => :tags
  indexes skill(:name), :as => :skill
  has :id
  has created_at
end
```

Sharing_skill.model

```
belongs_to :marker, :polymorphic => true
belongs_to :skill
```

Skill model.

```
has_one :sharing_skill
has_one :person, :through => :sharing_skill, :source => :marker
has_one :group, :through => :sharing_skill, :source => :marker
```

Search Controller.

```
#SEARCH NAME, TAGS, AND SKILL
conditions = {}
%w(name tags skill).each do |i|
  i = i.to_sym
  next unless params[i]
  conditions[i] = params[i]
end

person = Person.search(params[:search], :conditions => conditions, :per_page => 999999)
```